# Deployment of an application finished in tomcat but it is actually not deployed

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat8, catalina.out

Catalina.out:

```
[2020-04-10 11:48:26] [info] Manager: list: Listing contexts for virtual host 'localhost'

[2020-04-10 11:48:26] [info] Manager: install: Installing web application '/api#v1' from 'file:/home/kos/RPServers/available_webapps/reaper-webapp.war'

[2020-04-10 11:48:26] [info] **Deploying web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/reaper-app/api#v1.war]**

[2020-04-10 11:48:27] [info] 2020/04/10 11:48:27.897 - #2 - 4973/4193 - MemoryShield:  totalMemory = 3871.45 [MB] resMemory = 1311.47 [MB] shrMemory = 63.6523 [MB]

[2020-04-10 11:48:28] [info] At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.

[2020-04-10 11:48:28] [info] **Deployment of web application archive [/var/lib/tomcat8/webapps/reaper-app/api#v1.war] has finished in [2,345] ms**
```

Problem: The catalina.out logs tells that the deployment of an application is finished but the application is inaccessible (404 Error)

1. Any previous issue seen which is similar to this sort?
2. Or is it some config issue?
3. Or should more logging be enabled in logging.properties to understand the flow better?

Note: This is using Tomcat8

Thanks,

Comment: Are you sure the app is listening on the URL you are fetching?

Comment: Sorry, may I know which URL you are talking about?

Comment: The one that returns the 404.

Comment: Yes, the app listens on that URL

Comment: Well, obviously it doesn't. What I meant is please double check the configuration. You did not provide enough information for us to help in a meaningful way.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting same issue and found out that main class needs to be extended from **SpringBootServletInitializer**. Please check code below.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class MyApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MyApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was having the exact same issue as you described and I have also deployed it on tomcat 8, It turns out that the issue in my case was an incorrect version of java defined in pom.xml. I was deploying a war built with java 11 and it was silently failing

Changed the version to 1.8 rebuilt and deployed it and it worked